# type or namespace name "StreamReader" could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

I am working on StreamReader in C#. I am getting the error

> "The type or namespace name "StreamReader" could not be found"

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
class Perfect
{
static void Main()
    {
    string filename = @"marks.cvs";
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(line);    
    sr.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: I get the error, "The type or namespace name "StreamReader" could not be foud....."

Comment: Did you add `using System.IO;` in the using section of your class?

Comment: When I do that, I get: "The name "Console" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: You are using a Windows Forms structure.  Windows Forms doesn't normally feature a Console.  Go on your design surface and drag a textbox.  Then come back to your code and change Console.Writeline(line) to textBox1.Text = line.ToString();

Answer (score 11):

`StreamReader` is in the `System.IO` namespace.  You can add this namespace at the top of your code by doing the following-

```
using System.IO;
```

Alternatively, you could fully qualify all instances of `StreamReader` like so-

```
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
```

But this may get a little tedious, especially if you end up using other objects in `System.IO`.  Therefore I would recommend going with the former.

More on namespaces and the `using` directive-

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`StreamReader` requires a namespace which you are missing. Add these two at top of the .cs file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
```

Its always a best-practice to add namespace at top of the file. However, you can add like this `System.IO.StreamReader` mentioned by @iliketocode.

```
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
```

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't going to post the answer, but just had another good programming practice to point out.

Firstly, to answer your question, if you want to use `StreamReader` you need to tell the compiler where to find it. Adding a `using System.IO.StreamReader;` at the top of your .cs file would do that.

Secondly, when using streams, it is better to wrap your interaction with the stream in a `using(){}`. The way I would write your code would be:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.StreamReader;

class Perfect
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const string filename = @"marks.cvs";
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```